# CrossMediaManager.Current.Play doesn't play local audio file on iOS xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i try to use CrossMediaManager to play mp3 files after download in android it work very good but in ios nothing occurs

I use this code to play the file after download

```
 await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AE6136ED-28C4-482F-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/Documents/file.mp3");
```

and this code for download in DependencyService

```
  var url = new Uri("http://url.to.some/file.mp3");
var httpClient = new HttpClient ();
httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url).ContinueWith(data => {
    string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.mydocument);
    string localFilename = "downloaded.mp3";
    string localPath = Path.Combine (documentsPath, localFilename);
    File.WriteAllBytes (localPath, data.Result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this way to play your local music:

```
string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string localFilename = "downloaded.mp3";
string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);
var pathToFileURL = new System.Uri(localPath).AbsolutePath;
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file://" + pathToFileURL);
```

Comment: If your app is running on Android, besides correcly locating the audio file URI you also need to request Storage permission on Android manifest and/or at runtime, or else the file won't start playing.

Answer (score 0):

You download the mp3 file to `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` but try to play it from a hardcoded file path that seems to be invalid. You should build the play file path using the same pattern with `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` which should be something like:

```
$"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)}downloaded.mp3"
```

More details can be found in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/file-system).

Comment: this is Application output

 `Observer triggered for rate Observer
 triggered for rate Observer
 triggered for loadedTimeRanges 
Observer triggered for status Status
 Observed Method Unknown 
Observer triggered for rate -[AVAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:] invoked with unrecognized keys ( title, artwork, artist ). 
Observer triggered for rate
 Observer triggered for status Status
 Observed Method Faile`